# R - a function that changes 1 row value, one at a time

Tags: r, function

I'm new to R and working on a project, and have been asked to do something that's a couple notches more difficult than what I can currently do.

So I have a data set that looks alot like this:

```
    Obs.   Democracy  
     1        1 
     2        0
     3        1
     4        0
     5        1
     6        1 
     7        1
     8        0
     9        0
     10       1
```

The data set has other control variables, but the important variable is the binary one for democracy. We've run an OLS regression of the current data, and what we're looking to do now is to collect a list of regressions - where the independent variable is changed.

I'm trying to create a function where it changes the democracy variable from 0 to 1 row by row, and runs and stores an OLS regression inbetween each change.

I've read a bit about loops, mapply and functions, but haven't been able to write anything near what we're looking for.

The best I've been able to create isn't close:

```
    my.function <- function (data$democracy){
      GB1 <- ifelse(data$democracy[x,]==1, 1, 1)
      return(regression[x] <- glm(leader ~ democracy))
    }
```

My apologies if this is a duplicate, I found alot on similar topics, but wasn't able to use the information to write a functioning code.

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for every combination of 0 & 1 for all observations?

Comment: ultimately yes, but in trying to put everything together piece by piece, I was going to start with a smaller subset - all permutations that change 0s to 1s

Comment: To do the job on a smaller subset, use the answer by @Troy with a slight modification: `n <- sum(df$Democracy==0);
    cases <- rbind(rep(0, n), 1*lower.tri(matrix(1, n, n), diag=T))` It will replace `0` by `1` one by one, starting from the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exhaustive searching of all combinations will be intractable for all but the smallest datasets. I believe what you are looking for is a permutation P-value. For a fun introduction to this concept please check out the canonical ["Super Bowl Theory"](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Working/superbowl.pdf) example.

The idea is that if there is a real relationship between your dependent and independent variables, if you "mix-up" which observation of the dependent variable goes with each observation of the independent variable, there is a high probability that a test of that relationship will return a less extreme statistic.

Here is an example of calculating a permutation P-value using OLS R^2 as a statistic, with the built-in `iris` dataset:

```
data(iris)

get_statistic <- function() {
    return(summary(lm(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris))$r.squared)
}

## allocate an array to store our results
results <- rep(FALSE, 1000) 

## get the original statistic before we mix things up
original_statistic = get_statistic() 

for (i in 1:1000) { ## do 1000 permutations
    iris$Species = sample(iris$Species, 
        length(iris$Species), 
        replace = F)
    if (get_statistic() >= original_statistic) {
        ## if we beat the original statistic, mark this trial as True
        results[i] = T 
    }
}

## get the average number of trials that succeeded
## this is your p-value!
P_perm = mean(results)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text="Obs   Democracy  
1        1 
2        0
3        1
4        0
5        1
6        1 
7        1
8        0
9        0
10       1")

leader<-sample(c("A","B"),10,T)

cases<-expand.grid(lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x)0:1))   # gives you each possible combination of 0:1 * 10

apply(cases,1,function(democracy)glm(democracy~leader)) # returns a list of glms all 1024 combns
```

PS: if you just want to toggle all the 0s to 1 in sequence, you can use this code to create `cases`

```
zeros<-df$Obs[df$Democracy==0]
cases<-t(sapply(0:length(zeros),function(x){df$Democracy[df$Obs %in% zeros[0:x]]<-1
                                   df$Democracy}))
```

Comment: Nice trick with `expand.grid`! Another option is `bincombinations`  from package `e1071`.